# Why following C code compiles without an error?

Tags: c, bgi

My code is as follows:

```
void main()
{
    int gdriver=DETECT, gmode;

    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, " ");

    getch();

    closegraph();
}
```

Though the value of graphics mode(gmode) has not been initialized, its address has been passed into the program...and it compiles with no error!

Is it not wrong to pass the address of a variable without initializing that variable?

Comment: `void main` alone is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/1619294

Comment: You're passing a _pointer_ to the variable to the function, and the pointer isn't uninitialized, just what it points to.

Comment: If `initgraph` writes `gmode` before anyone reads it, where's the error? Now ask: how would the compiler looking at `main` know whether this is true or not?

Answer (score 2):

You pass the address of `gmode`, not a reference to it. You don't need to initialize `gmode`, because the function `initgraph()` might do so.

You might get a warning though, depending on the compiler and the compiler options, you use.

Answer (score 0):

First, although you have tagged C++ as well, in the above code the passing of the argument is NOT pass by reference but pass by value.

`graphics mode(gmode) has not been initialized`

Second, it should not give you an error because it is not a reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

now I got the answer...when we write `gdriver=DETECT`, it returns the value for both - for `gdriver` and for `gmode`.

This is because `DETECT` is an enumerated data type that maps the `gdriver` and `gmode` to according graphics driver and mode value. That is why we do not require to initialize `gmode` before passing its address.